# Android BLE logcat error: E/bt_btif: bta_gattc_process_indicate, ignore HID ind/notificiation

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I have an app which communicates with a BLE device. It sends data packets @ 40hz to the phone. I'm using [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) and everything works as it should (mostly anyway)

I'm currently trying to optimise for cpu and battery, and noticed for each packet received from the BLE device, i see the following in logcat:
`E/bt_btif: bta_gattc_process_indicate, ignore HID ind/notificiation`

This can't be great for cpu/battery consumption, logging at 40hz... it also means useful logs dissapear as they're pushed out by these chatty ones.
My device isn't a HID - as far as i can work out.

Q1: What does this log even mean?
Q2: How do i stop it?

Sorry for asking a previously answered question, but there aren't any good answers and i wanted to ask under #rxandroidbe to see if there's something configurable in the libary.

Comment: Have you any information about this?  I'm using a different library on android REACT-NATIVE-BLE-MANAGER and am seeing this message flood my logcat.  My device is not an HID and would love to know if there is a way to stop these messages.

Comment: Sorry, nothing came of this. I just ignored it and tried not to think about it :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact error in `onCharacteristicChanged`. It turned out that I was doing too much work in `onCharacteristicChanged`. For reasons that I can't remember I thought that it was a good idea to launch a Kotlin coroutine in that callback on every notification for streaming data. We're talking something like 100 notifications per second and every one was launching a coroutine. It was actually a terrible idea.

Once I cleaned up that method the error spam went away. I searched pretty extensively before arriving at that point and could not find any meaningful way to decipher the error from ADB Logcat so I started poking around in the source. Hopefully that info helps somebody else out in the future.

source: [bta_gattc_act.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/jb-mr1-release/bta/gatt/bta_gattc_act.c)